# How to get inheriting class int members?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, .net-4.0

I have a base class like this:

```
public class Marker {
     public int[] GetChildMarks() {
          //Somehow Get Child int members
     }
     public int ShallNotBeInArray;
}

public class MyMarker : Marker {
   public int Size, Number;
}

public class TedsMarker : Marker {
   public int Power;
}

//... somewhere in main
var m = new MyMarker(){Size=3, Number = 666};
var arr = m.GetChildMarks(); // [Size, Number, Any other ints in MyMarker ]
var t = new TedsMarker() {Power=999};
var arr2 = t.GetChildMarks(); // [Power, Any other ints in TedsMarker]
```

So is it possible and how one can do such a thing in C# using reflection?

Comment: Make `Marker` an abstract class. Make `GetChildMarks` abstract and implement it in `MyMarker'

Comment: That is the point - not to implement it in child class - so API user could just write a super short markup like class definition and have it all done for him automagically

Comment: What's the point of such a derived class?

Comment: Do you want to call `GetChildMarks` from a static context or with a instance of type `MyMarker`?

Comment: Then use reflection. It is auto magic with no boundaries (Are the property names in all the child classes the same?)

Comment: In fact, I do believe what you want could be done with `Dictionary<string,int>` without `Marker` base class and derivatives whatsoever.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: please see an updated question - tried to clarify that I want all child int memebers, not specifically named ones.

Comment: I don't get it. If you don't even need the names then pass around `int[]` ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved like this:

```
public class Marker
{
    public int[] GetChildMarks()
    {
        return new int[]
        {
            (int)GetType().GetField("Size").GetValue(this),
            (int)GetType().GetField("Number").GetValue(this)
        };
    }
    public int ShallNotBeInArray;
}
```

This assumes that the child class has these two fields and they are of type `int`.

Since there is no enforcement (and actually there can't be because these are fields, not properties), this approach is a good candidate to produce runtime errors.

EDIT:

The values of all the fields can be retrieved like this:

```
public class Marker
{
    public int[] GetChildMarks()
    {
        List<int> allIntegerFields = new List<int>();
        // DeclaredOnly: only get fields declared by this type, not the ones declared by base classes
        // Public | Instance: Only get non-static, public fields
        foreach(FieldInfo fieldInfo in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if(fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(int))
            {
                allIntegerFields.Add((int)fieldInfo.GetValue(this));
            }
        }
        return allIntegerFields.ToArray();
    }
    public int ShallNotBeInArray;
}
```

Comment: runtime errors are Ok with me, yet please see updated question - I wanted all children marks, not the specifically named ones.